# How to insert a <p> tag's text into its parent element as a data attribute?

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="content_section_item" data-item="">
  <img src="">
  <p>table</p>
</div>
<div class="content_section_item" data-item="">
  <img src="">
  <p>table</p>
</div>
<div class="content_section_item" data-item="">
  <img src="">
  <p>others</p>
</div>
```

How do I make a loop that takes the inner text of every p tag and puts it into the data-item attribute of its respective div parent like this:

```
<div class="content_section_item" data-item="table">
  <img src="">
  <p>table</p>
</div>
<div class="content_section_item" data-item="table">
  <img src="">
  <p>table</p>
</div>
<div class="content_section_item" data-item="others">
  <img src="">
  <p>others</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! How are you generating this HTML? Are you using a PHP loop to do this?

Comment: hey @disinfor, I have a gallery and create the divs using a CMS system. Now I would want that the p tag gets inserted into the data-item of the div because I use the data item to filter the gallery

Comment: What CMS are you using? Are you creating the loop that outputs that code? Or is it from a plugin and you aren't actually coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the divs. In each div, use `querySelector()` to find the nested `p`, get its contents with `.textContent`, and assign that to the div's `data-item` property.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div.content_section_item').forEach(
    div => div.dataset.item = div.querySelector('p').innerText
);
```

```html
<div class="content_section_item" data-item="">
  <img src="">
  <p>table</p>
</div>
<div class="content_section_item" data-item="">
  <img src="">
  <p>table</p>
</div>
<div class="content_section_item" data-item="">
  <img src="">
  <p>others</p>
</div>
```